# onclick event for node in kendo tree view, mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Im implementing some orgchart, im new to mvc and kendo..
how do i implement onclick event for thekendo tree view

```
Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                .Name("TreeViewTemplateBiding")                        
                .TemplateId("TreeViewTemplate")                             
                        .BindTo((IEnumerable<OrgChart.Models.NodeViewModel>)ViewBag.Tree, (Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.NavigationBindingFactory<TreeViewItem> mappings) =>
                           {
                               mappings.For<OrgChart.Models.NodeViewModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, node) =>
                               {
                                   item.Id = node.Id;
                                   item.Text = node.Title;
                                   //item.Expanded = node.Expanded;
                               })
                       .Children(node => node.Children));
                           })                               
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no 'click' event for kendo tree but there is 'select' event instead of 'click'. You can create event handler like this:

```
Html.Kendo().TreeView()
            .Name("TreeViewTemplateBiding")                        
            .TemplateId("TreeViewTemplate")                             
                    .BindTo((IEnumerable<OrgChart.Models.NodeViewModel>)ViewBag.Tree, (Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.NavigationBindingFactory<TreeViewItem> mappings) =>
                       {
                           mappings.For<OrgChart.Models.NodeViewModel>(binding => binding.ItemDataBound((item, node) =>
                           {
                               item.Id = node.Id;
                               item.Text = node.Title;
                               //item.Expanded = node.Expanded;
                           })
                   .Children(node => node.Children));
                       })
           .Events(e => e
            .Select("onSelect")
           )            
   )
```

And on Script you can call :

```
function onSelect(e){
   kendoConsole.log("Selecting: " + this.text(e.node));
}
```

There is demo for more treeview events : http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/treeview/events

Comment: thank u this works fine,but i need to select item.id value ...Can u Help me with this